# python wxpython global name not defined

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to develop a very simple wxpython GUI. At the moment there is just a button which opens a file dialog & underneath that a text control box. For the moment all I am trying to do is print the opened filename to the text control box, but keep getting an error message. " global name not defined ". Any help would be appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog as MDD

wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py|" \
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()

        text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "",style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL)

        # create the buttons and bindings
        openFileDlgBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Show OPEN FileDialog")
        openFileDlgBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFile)

        # put the buttons in a sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(openFileDlgBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(text, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onOpenFile(self, event):
        """
        Create and show the Open FileDialog
        """
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Choose a file",
            defaultDir=self.currentDirectory, 
            defaultFile="",
            wildcard=wildcard,
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            paths = dlg.GetPaths()
            print "You chose the following file(s):"
            for path in paths:
                print path
                text.AppendText('path') 
        dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback, including the error message. What you posted here is not nearly enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm new to programming so would not have a clue how to do a full trace back :-) The code that appears to be the problem is text.AppendText('path') Previously I just printed variable "path" to the console to make sure it worked, now I wish to print that variable to the text control widget, but I keep geeting that error appear in the console window.

Comment: When Python gives you an error, a full error message with traceback is printed. Nothing special needs to be done. It includes the `global name ... not defined` exception message at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an educated guess, based solely on eyeballing your code:

You refer to `text` in the `onOpenFile()` method, but don't define it in that method. `text` is a local name in a different method instead.

If you want to reach the `TextCtrl` object you assigned to `text` in the `__init__` method, store a reference to it on `self` so you can refer to it in other methods too:

```
def __init__(self):
    # ....
    self.text = text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "",style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL)

def onOpenFile(self, event):
    # ....
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        paths = dlg.GetPaths()
        print "You chose the following file(s):"
        for path in paths:
            print path
            self.text.AppendText('path')
```

Comment: That sounds exactly right, but being new to programming not sure how. Could you give me an example please.